# Get part of url in php

Tags: php

I want to get a part of this url using php, what will be best approach

example url:

```
http://www.domain.com/44-Paris/blogs-for-travel/tour1.html
```

How do I get url like one below using php?

**http://www.domain.com/44-Paris/**

Comment: What have you already tried yourself? PHP has excellent documentation that should be able to help you achieve what you need.

Comment: Try read up on http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

Comment: It depends on what you need. Do you want to remove the last two parts, keep only the first, get the first 31 characters, remove the last 5 words... all these conditions will result in the same string when passed this exact url.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use [parse_url](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)

```
<?php
    $url = 'http://www.domain.com/44-Paris/blogs-for-travel/tour1.html';

    $parse = parse_url($url);
    $path = explode('/', $parse['path']);

    echo $parse['scheme']."://".$parse['host']."/".$path[1]."/";
?>
```

Comment: +1 for good answer. Little Addition. Could be made into a function so just input url into required variable if required more than once.