# get main url part of big link

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get part of url in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10140504/get-part-of-url-in-php)

i want to get `http://aoup.net/manage/preForm/test.php`

from this url

```
http://aoup.net/manage/preForm/test.php?op=Results&form_id=1&form_name=%D8%A7%D9%86%D8%AA%D8%AE%D8%A7%D8%A8%20%D8%AD%D9%88%D8%B2%D9%87%20%D8%A7%D9%85%D8%AA%D8%AD%D8%A7%D9%86%DB%8C%28%D8%AF%D9%88%D8%B1%D9%87%20228%29&hash=406ce38266577b8dff3102e476fdf587
```

this my php code not work correctly:

```
echo 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `parse_url` function to achieve this: http://es2.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

For example:

```
<?php

$url = 'http://aoup.net/manage/preForm/test.php?op=Results&form_id=1&form_name=%D8%A7%D9%86%D8%AA%D8%AE%D8%A7%D8%A8%20%D8%AD%D9%88%D8%B2%D9%87%20%D8%A7%D9%85%D8%AA%D8%AD%D8%A7%D9%86%DB%8C%28%D8%AF%D9%88%D8%B1%D9%87%20228%29&hash=406ce38266577b8dff3102e476fdf587';
$parsed_url = parse_url($url);
$new_url = $parsed_url['scheme'] . '://' . $parsed_url['host'] . $parsed_url['path'];
echo $new_url;
```

Will print `http://aoup.net/manage/preForm/test.php`

Answer (score 2):

```
echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];
```